# How to apply several Indexers and Encoders without creating countless intermediate DataFrames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Here's my code :

```
val workindexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("workclass").setOutputCol("workclassIndex")
val workencoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("workclassIndex").setOutputCol("workclassVec")

val educationindexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("education").setOutputCol("educationIndex")
val educationencoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("educationIndex").setOutputCol("educationVec")

val maritalindexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("marital_status").setOutputCol("maritalIndex")
val maritalencoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("maritalIndex").setOutputCol("maritalVec")

val occupationindexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("occupation").setOutputCol("occupationIndex")
val occupationencoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("occupationIndex").setOutputCol("occupationVec")

val relationindexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("relationship").setOutputCol("relationshipIndex")
val relationencoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("relationshipIndex").setOutputCol("relationshipVec")

val raceindexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("race").setOutputCol("raceIndex")
val raceencoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("raceIndex").setOutputCol("raceVec")

val sexindexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("sex").setOutputCol("sexIndex")
val sexencoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("sexIndex").setOutputCol("sexVec")

val nativeindexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("native_country").setOutputCol("native_countryIndex")
val nativeencoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("native_countryIndex").setOutputCol("native_countryVec")

val labelindexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("label").setOutputCol("labelIndex")
```

Is there any way to apply all these encoders and indexers without creating countless intermediate dataframes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `RFormula`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RFormula

val features = Seq("workclass", "education", 
   "marital_status", "occupation", "relationship", 
   "race", "sex", "native", "country")

val formula = new RFormula().setFormula(s"label ~ ${features.mkString(" + ")}")
```

It will apply the same transformations as the indexers used in the example and assemble the features `Vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the feature of Spark MLlib called [ML Pipelines](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html):

> **ML Pipelines** provide a uniform set of high-level APIs built on top of DataFrames that help users create and tune practical machine learning pipelines.

With ML Pipelines you could "chain" (or "pipe") the *"encoders and indexers without creating countless intermediate dataframes"*.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml._
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(workindexer, workencoder...))
```